# MISSING RIGHT PARENTHESIS ERROR WITH PARENTHESIS CORRECT

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running an SQL query and have just two parenthesis but I still get the error "missing parenthesis". The code is shown below:

```
Update ALEKWE_CUSTOMER C
     set recently_purchased = CASE  WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ALEKWE_CUSTOMER_PRODUCT AS D
            WHERE C.customer_id=D.customer_id) 
            THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END;
```

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.  As for your question, the query looks ok.  One problem may be that you are running other code without realizing it, such a code in a file or winder before this statement.

Comment: instead of writing this post u must have corrected the existing markup. and look for missing/extra parenthesis right?

Answer (score 0):

If this is for sql-server, then this might be the answer:

```
Update ALEKWE_CUSTOMER 
set recently_purchased = (CASE WHEN EXISTS(
SELECT * FROM ALEKWE_CUSTOMER_PRODUCT AS D WHERE customer_id=D.customer_id) THEN 'Y' 
ELSE 'N' END);
```

You need to put the whole `CASE` structure in parentheses too.
Next to that, you can't use an alias for the table which will be updated.

Comment: He said it's for Oracle. And no, you don't need to put the whole case structure in parantheses.

Comment: @Quandary He hadn't specified which database it was when I answered. But you are correct, it doesn't need the parentheses, I just find it more readable. I should have said that instead of 'need'.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the alias C at this position, and neither do you need it:

```
Update ALEKWE_CUSTOMER 
     set recently_purchased = CASE  WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ALEKWE_CUSTOMER_PRODUCT AS D
            WHERE ALEKWE_CUSTOMER.customer_id=D.customer_id) 
            THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END;
```

You don't need to put the case into paranteses either.

You would need:

```
Update ALEKWE_CUSTOMER 
     set recently_purchased = CASE  WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ALEKWE_CUSTOMER_PRODUCT AS D
            WHERE C.customer_id=D.customer_id) 
            THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END;
FROM ALEKWE_CUSTOMER C
```

for your alias to work

**Edit:**

My altered statements work fine on Microsoft SQL-Server. 
**Apparently the problem is specific to Oracle SQL**.
After reading your comments, I added Oracle to your tags, since you say this nowhere.

Comment: i have tried this code the error is still coming out,am running it on toad oracle

Comment: This is the statement i am actually trying to run:Update ALEKWE_CUSTOMER C
set recently_purchased = ( case when  DATE_PURCHASED BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-12) AND SYSDATE then 'Y' else 'N' end
from ALEKWE_CUSTOMER_PRODUCT D
where C.customer_id=D.customer_id)       and its still bringing out the right parenthesis error

Comment: @user3752199: Then you should put oracle in the tags. It works fine on Microsoft SQL-Server (tested on 2008 R2).

Comment: @user3752199 you are still using the alias `C`. You should really try it without that alias, as the answers tell you to do.